# Click download CSV image to download the CSV file in Selinium python

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am completely new to Selinium. I am trying to download a csv file from a web page (https://www.nseindia.com/option-chain). After selecting the drop down `View Options Contracts for` and selecting `BANKNIFTY` and then selecting `Expiry Date` and then selecting `08-Jul-2021`, `Download csv` need to clicked to download the file.

I managed to do selecting dropdowns using below code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get('https://www.nseindia.com/option-chain')
time.sleep(3)

select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('equity_optionchain_select'))


# # select by value
select.select_by_value('BANKNIFTY')
time.sleep(3)

select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('expirySelect'))
# # select by value
select.select_by_value('08-Jul-2021')

# non working code trying to click download button/image
download_elem = driver.find_element_by_id('downloadOCTable')
print(download_elem)
download_elem.click()
```

I need to click the download CSV button (image is clickable in web page) to download the CSV file.

In chrome browser, in the inspect option, I am seeing the code for this part as below.

```
<div class="xlsdownload">
   <a id="downloadOCTable" download="option-chain-equity-derivatives.csv" href="javascript:;" onclick="downloadOCFile(this, 'equity')"><img src="/assets/images/icon-xls.svg" alt="csv" title="csv"> Download (.csv)</a>
</div>
```

I am trying in this way which is not working.
driver.find_element_by_id('downloadOCTable').click()

Could anyone suggest how to handle this case.

Answer (score 0):

The following using css selector ,should be able to click the link. i tried it and downloaded the csv file

```
download = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#downloadOCTable')
download.click()
sleep(10)
browser.quit()
```